# Storing socket.io socket object in memory and synchronizing within node processes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mongoose

I have a node app which is right now running on single core processor , but very soon im going to use cluster and sync socket.io with redis for multiple node.js processes . I store connected clients(socket.io's socket object) in memory i.e something like

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   clients[someId][someId2] = socket;
})
```

So all the sockets are in clients object . But this clients object has different sockets for each node.js process (since they have seperate memory ) .

Now if i `clients[someId][someId2].emit('something')` from node.js process (1) and if that `client[someId][someId2]` is actually in node.js process(2) , i have problem .

So how to deal with this , how to share a common object between all node.js processes ? Im very new to cluster and havent worked with so far .

**EDIT** :

I just learnt that workers forked through cluster cannot share and the efficient working solution for this problems is to create node.js processes with different ports each and have sticky sessions with load balancer (like HAProxy) . But consider this , **client1** is connected to nodejsP1 and is in clientsOfP1[client1] = socket; and client2 to nodeJsP2 ,
Now if Client1's session wants to do something like clientsOfP2[client2].emit , it has to communicate with P2 with some IPC like ZeroMQ . Is this good for production ?

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to use a database like Redis and, for message passing, a queue system like [Kue](http://learnboost.github.io/kue/). It's extremely common to use a queue system like RabbitMQ, Resque, or Kue to enable IPC. At some point, you will outgrow one server anyway and need to be able to communicate on processes between servers.

**Update**:

Because Node is explicitly single process, it is not optimized for multi-process communication. This makes particular sense for environments like Heroku and small EC2 instances, where your architecture is to scale horizontally across many machines, rather than trying to satisfy all demand from a single big server. This is called [horizontal, share-nothing scaling](http://12factor.net/processes), and is a core principle of 12 factor design.

Comment: So it is better for server cluster to share the same Redis store, where the socket data will be kept or to have a message queue to send the data between different servers when message is addressing a socket on another machine?

Comment: Either is fine, but you'll likely want to share the Redis store between servers anyway for session cookies. If so, you should consider implementing Kue or Resque on top.